# How do I get an auth token for a facebook page if my app has been added to it?

Tags: facebook, api, authentication

My app's only purpose is to make posts as Facebook pages, so we'd like to take user login out of the flow.

If the user adds our app to their page using a link like http://facebook.com/add.php?api_key=APP_KEY&pages=1, how would I get an access token to make posts as that page?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least one of the page's admins has to authorize your app with both `manage_pages` and `publish_stream` permissions. (see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/)

Then once you get their access token, call the graph with `me/accounts` and in that list will be the page. (see the Page Login section of https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/)  In there will be a page access token for managing that page. So then you can HTTP Post to  me/feed a new message using that page access token.

Happy coding!

Comment: BTW, you **cannot** take the user login out of the flow.  the only way to get a page access_token is to get it from an authorized admin of that page.